# how to pass value to a function in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am passing this value true to function below can anyone help me.....
I can use simple javascript function in place of jquery but for the sake of knowledge i want to make it in this way.

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#slider").click(function(){
    $("#slider").suyesh(true);
    });
});

(function($){
    $.fn.suyesh = function(s){
        if(s == true){
            alert("value is coming");   
            }
        }
})(jQuery);
```

**HTML :**

```
<div id="slider">
        <ul class="slide">
            <li class="slide_1"><img src="1.jpg"></li>
            <li class="slide_2"><img src="2.jpg"></li>
            <li class="slide_3"><img src="3.jpg"></li>
            <li class="slide_4"><img src="4.jpg"></li>
            <li class="slide_5"><img src="5.jpg"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where does the *true* value come from?

Comment: You're not going to get much help with a question of this... quality. What exactly are you trying to achieve, your intentions aren't clear at all? I recommend you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ example for people to play with.

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/8Z4h6/

Comment: How is the function `suyesh` defined? If it is a function of the original javascript object, try `$("#slider")[0].suyesh(true);`.

Comment: ok guys i ll try to improve my question and more informative.

Comment: You're probably looking for how to write jQuery plugins.  Google for that and you'll get lots of example on how to design your `suyesh()` function.

Comment: What is the problem ?...your code is working fine .. see here :- http://jsfiddle.net/jqNCs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking at creating a jQuery plugin.  Try something like:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.suyesh = function(myArg) {
        if (myArg) {
            // Put code here to do thing if true was passed in.
            // i.e. this.css("color", "green");
        } else {
            // Put code here to do thing if false was passed in.
            // i.e. this.css("color", "red");
        }
        return this;
    }; 
}(jQuery));
```